# Using shell script to select static IPv4 configuration according to router address

Tags: networking, ip

I have Linux Mint 15, I live in a university where the hostel and lab have separate static IP settings. Is there a way to set up the connection mechanism so that my laptop will automatically select the correct configuration according to which router is serving it?

EDIT: My question is actually case specific to wired connection, but would be interested to know about both.

Comment: Is it wireless? If so, `network-manager` can do that, but based on the ESSID and not the gateways IP.

Comment: Edited my question. It's specific to wired LAN, but would like to know for both. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but what is a "hostel"?

Comment: aka dormitory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had a chance to fully vet this yet but I did find this guide which sounds like what you're asking to do. It discusses the application of static IPs that can be applied through NetworkManager, which would in theory, have access to the network information when your laptop moves from one network to another.

The guide is titled: [Roaming Profiles with NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RoamingProfilesWithNetworkManager). The section on static IPs is titled: [Static IP Assignment Kludge](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RoamingProfilesWithNetworkManager#Static_IP_Assignment_Kludge).

Comment: @AdeeshLemonickous - Glad this resolved your issue, please mark this as the accepted answer so others know your issue's been resolved.